# how to track user location and make the route with google map

Tags: javascript, android, ios, google-maps

I would like to ask you an idea. How to create a mobile application like starve or runtastic which can record user location in realtime and after user finish traveling, the app can draw the route that user traveled and show to them as a result. During user is traveling the app also find any places nearby the user location (places are stored in my database).

Please give me any idea.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to Use google Location API and map API. To setup map, follow this tutorial: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_google_maps.htm,

and to use the locationManager, follow this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2015/02/android-location-api-using-google-play-services/.

To draw the polyLine on different positions covered by the user, you might have to track every position longitude and latitude and draw the polyLine along the path. For detailed info, checkout google Api on map and location 
at http://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html.

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Your Question is very vague.

To start with you will need Google Maps API key that renders a map to your fragment.

Current locations can be enabled by

```
GoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

After Asking a users destination you will use Google Maps Directions API with a Server key to opt for a route in form on JSON or XML through a URL.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/output?origin="origin_location&destination="final_destination"&mode="traveling_mode"&alternatives="true"&key="ServerAPIkey"
```

You must pass this URL for a string with JSON or XML(output) data.
And use that data to draw polyline for your route.

To Read complete details, it is adviced that you read google documentations on their developers website.

Cheers.